# Define constant and use in Excel 2010 formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

A quick question. What would be the Excel 2010 equivalent of the programming define

```
#define YES 1
#define NO 0
```

So if I enter in a cell =YES+YES+NO for example, it return 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning equivalency to #define, I can't say.
BUT

If the goal is to sum YES+NO entries you might try

```
Function addYesNo(rng As Range)
 Dim x As String
 x = Replace(Replace(rng, "YES", 1), "NO", 0)
 addYesNo = Evaluate("=SUM(" & x & ")")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be ugly, but you can put those values in cells and then make named ranges that point to those cells. Then you can just reference the named ranges in your formulas.